# задача об обедающих философах C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Сдал задачу об обедающих философах, но преподаватель отправил обратно, сказав, что код написан неверно, не сообщив где именно.

> Одной из классических задач компьютерных наук является Задача об обедающих философах. Придумал её знаменитый Эдсгер Дейкстра в 1965 году.
> Как известно, каждый философ может находится в одном из двух состояний: он либо думает, либо кушает. И вот однажды философы решили собраться, чтобы покушать и подумать.
>
> Согласно легенде пять безмолвных философов сидят вокруг круглого стола перед каждым философом стоит тарелка спагетти. Вилки лежат на столе между каждой парой ближайших философов. Т.е. на столе 5 тарелок и 5 вилок.
>
> Вся проблема в том, что спагетти очень скользкие и чтобы их удержать нужно сразу две вилки. Поэтому когда каждый из философов пытается поесть, он берёт и вилку лежащую справа и вилку лежащую слева.
>
> Если мы перейдём к технической терминологии, то философы - это потоки, а вилки - это какой-то разделяемый ограниченный ресурс.
>
> Теоретически возможна следующая ситуация:
>
> Потоки запускаются одновременно, каждый философ поднимает правую вилку, вилок на столе не остаётся и никто не может взять левую. Все кладут обратно правую. Ждут. После чего снова одновременно поднимают правую и всё повторяется.
>
> Таким образом теоретически возможна ситуация блокировки всех потоков - deadlock.
>
> На практике полная блокировка происходи очень редко, ведь в системе работают и другие программы и вероятность, что все потоки сделают эти действия синхронно очень мала, но с точки зрения компьютерных наук нас волнует тот факт, что такая ситуация теоретически возможна. Нам нужно это исправить.
>
> Задача
>
> Доработать этот код так, чтобы даже теоретически убрать возможность возникновения deadlock. Количество баллов за решение задачи будет ставиться в зависимости от того, насколько предоставленное решение соответствует следующим критерия:
>
> - Ресурсы равномерно распределяются между философами (при одинаковом поведении философы едят примерно одинаковое количество раз, никто их них не получает преимущества)
> - Одновременно могут есть несколько философов
> - Реализация масштабируется (соотношение приёмов пищи не меняется при увеличении количества философов)

---

Моя попытка

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace philosophers_os
{
    class Fork
    {
        private Mutex m = new Mutex();

        public void take()
        {
            m.WaitOne();
           
        }

        public void put()
        {
            m.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    };

    class Philosopher 
    {
        
        int id;

        private int count_phil;
        int count_eating_phi;

        Fork fork_left;
        Fork fork_right;

        uint eat_count;
        double wait_time;

        DateTime wait_start;
        //Флаг остановки философа
        bool stop_flag;
        bool debug_flag;

        Random random;
        Program program;

        public Philosopher(int number, Fork left, Fork right, bool dbg, int N)
        {
            this.id = number;
            this.fork_left = left;
            this.fork_right = right;
            this.eat_count = 0;
            this.wait_time = 0;
            this.debug_flag = dbg;
            this.stop_flag = false;
            this.random = new Random();
            this.count_phil = N / 2;
        }

        //Философ думает 
        void think()
        {
            if (this.debug_flag)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.id + " thinking");
            }

            Thread.Sleep(this.random.Next(0, 100));

            if (this.debug_flag)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.id + " hungry");
            }

            this.wait_start = DateTime.Now;
        }

        //Философ кушает
        void eat()
        {
            this.wait_time += DateTime.Now.Subtract(this.wait_start).TotalMilliseconds;
            if (this.debug_flag)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.id + " eating");
            }

            Thread.Sleep(this.random.Next(0, 100));

            eat_count++;
        }

      
        //Запустили работу философа
        public void run()
        {
            program = new Program();
            while (!stop_flag)
            {
                think();

                this.fork_left.take();
                if (this.debug_flag)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(this.id + " took left fork");
                }

                this.fork_right.take();
                if (this.debug_flag)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(this.id + " took right fork");
                }
                
                program.count_eating++;

                eat();

                this.fork_right.put();
                if (this.debug_flag)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(this.id + " put right fork");
                }

                this.fork_left.put();
                if (this.debug_flag)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(this.id + " put left fork");
                }
                program.count_eating--;
            }
        }

        //Остановили работу философа
        public void stop()
        {
            stop_flag = true;
        }

        //Вывод статуса в консоль
        public void printStats()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.id + " " + this.eat_count + " " + Convert.ToInt32(this.wait_time));
        }
    };

    class Program
    {
        public int count_eating;
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int N = 5;
            bool dbg = false;
           
            int duration = 60000; //60 сек

            //Создали вилки
            Fork[] forks = new Fork[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                forks[i] = new Fork();
            }

            //Создали философов
            Philosopher[] phils = new Philosopher[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                phils[i] = new Philosopher(i + 1, forks[(i + 1) % N], forks[i], dbg, N);
            }

            //Дали каждому философу по потоку и запустили потоки
            Thread[] runners = new Thread[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                runners[i] = new Thread(phils[i].run);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                runners[i].Start();
            }

            //Время работы программы ограничили 
            Thread.Sleep(duration);

            //Запомнили когда поток остановлен
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                phils[i].stop();
            }

            //Остановили все потоки
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                runners[i].Join();
            }

            //Вывели сколько раз ел и сколько раз ждал
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                phils[i].printStats();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код исходный

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace philosophers_os
{
    class Fork
    {
        private Mutex m = new Mutex();

        public void take()
        {
            m.WaitOne();
        }

        public void put()
        {
            m.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    };

    class Philosopher
    {
        int id;
        Fork fork_left;
        Fork fork_right;
        uint eat_count;
        double wait_time;
        DateTime wait_start;
        bool stop_flag;
        bool debug_flag;
        Random random;

        void think()
        {
            if (this.debug_flag)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.id + " thinking");
            }

            Thread.Sleep(this.random.Next(0, 100));

            if (this.debug_flag)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.id + " hungry");
            }

            this.wait_start = DateTime.Now;
        }

        void eat()
        {
            this.wait_time += DateTime.Now.Subtract(this.wait_start).TotalMilliseconds;
            if (this.debug_flag)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.id + " eating");
            }

            Thread.Sleep(this.random.Next(0, 100));

            eat_count++;
        }

        public Philosopher(int number, Fork left, Fork right, bool dbg)
        {
            this.id = number;
            this.fork_left = left;
            this.fork_right = right;
            this.eat_count = 0;
            this.wait_time = 0;
            this.debug_flag = dbg;
            this.stop_flag = false;
            this.random = new Random();
        }

        public void run()
        {
            while (!stop_flag)
            {
                think();

                this.fork_left.take();
                if (this.debug_flag)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(this.id + " took left fork");
                }

                this.fork_right.take();
                if (this.debug_flag)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(this.id + " took right fork");
                }

                eat();

                this.fork_right.put();
                if (this.debug_flag)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(this.id + " put right fork");
                }

                this.fork_left.put();
                if (this.debug_flag)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(this.id + " put left fork");
                }
            }
        }

        public void stop()
        {
            stop_flag = true;
        }

        public void printStats()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.id + " " + this.eat_count + " " + Convert.ToInt32(this.wait_time));
        }
    };

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int N = 5;
            bool dbg = false;
            int duration = 60000;

            Fork[] forks = new Fork[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                forks[i] = new Fork();
            }

            Philosopher[] phils = new Philosopher[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                phils[i] = new Philosopher(i + 1, forks[(i + 1) % N], forks[i], dbg);
            }

            Thread[] runners = new Thread[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                runners[i] = new Thread(phils[i].run);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                runners[i].Start();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(duration);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                phils[i].stop();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                runners[i].Join();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                phils[i].printStats();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Patterns of Parallel Programming](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) - прочитаете, легко решите задачу.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо, теперь решение проблемы растянется на несколько суток)))

Comment: @aepot готово!!

Comment: `program = new Program();` это вот зачем? Зачем вам для каждого потока своя `program.count_eating`? Как вы планировали ее использовать? Пока я вижу, что вы ее вообще не используете. Как выглядел изначальный код, предоставленный к задаче? Можете добавить его отдельно, чтобы понимать, где ваш код, а где не ваш?

Comment: Результаты беглого поиска: [1](https://habr.com/ru/post/447898/), [2](https://github.com/seanconnollydev/dining-philosophers/blob/master/DiningPhilosophers/Program.cs), [3](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%85), [4](https://thuru.net/2012/01/09/dinning-philosopher-c/), [5](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1239410/Dining-Philosophers-Problem). Изучив ссылки, я вижу даже несколько способов решения этой, как оказалось, очень попсовой задачи.

Comment: @aepot буду честен с вам немного.  я попытался исправить исходный код и потерпел фиаско. (добавил исходный) я в панике. смотрю на рения понимаю что нужно сделать начинаю смотреть на свой код и туплю.

Comment: Смотрели книжку, на которую я дал ссылку? Там в конце решение этой задачи с объяснением. Автор книги - гуру дотнета, параллельности, многопоточности, асинхронности, так что ознакомиться стоит.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я начал изучать книгу. В разгар сессии трудно изучать что-то, тем более она на английском, а я знаю его на уровне сходить в магазин и купить что-то или спросить дорогу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как решений и объяснений в сети очень много ([1](https://habr.com/ru/post/447898/), [2](https://github.com/seanconnollydev/dining-philosophers/blob/master/DiningPhilosophers/Program.cs), [3](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%85), [4](https://thuru.net/2012/01/09/dinning-philosopher-c/), [5](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1239410/Dining-Philosophers-Problem)), задача очень популярная, писать еще одно решение не вижу смысла.

Просто уловите общую логику решения, ведь условие очень простое: как даже теоретически исключить возможность появляения deadlock? Рандомизация времени - штука прикольная, но в реальной жизни это не работает, потому что в высоконагруженных приложениях не 5 философов, а например 50000, и вероятность коллизии критически высока. То есть если даже теоретически существует вероятность deadlock - он обязательно произойдет. Как избежать?

Могут ли 2 соседа заблокировать друг друга? Не могут, потому что один из них схватит вилку, второй будет ждать. Получается возможна только циклическая блокировка, когда все философы держат одну и ту же вилку, о которой написано в задаче. Избегает ли такой блокировки ваш код из вопроса? Нет, не на 100%. Вся надежда на рандомизатор. Поэтому преподаватель вас и развернул. Представьте, что рандомизатор сошел с ума и нагенерил вам нулей `Thread.Sleep(0)`, а потоки стартанули одновременно. Либо разное время старта потоков компенсировалось рандомизатором и все потоки схватили правую вилку одновременно. Может такое быть? Да легко. И "маловероятно" здесь - не решение, потому что в условии написано *Доработать этот код так, чтобы даже **теоретически** убрать возможность возникновения deadlock.*

А что нужно, чтобы избежать "даже **теоретически**" дедлока? Да чтобы один поток не хватал вообще вилки вообще, когда все остальные уже схватили как минимум одну. Для этого надо считать схвативших. Чтобы решить задачу вам нужен "официант", дающий разрешение на взятие первой вилки, и `SemaphoreSlim` на мой взгляд - здесь очень хороший инструмент. Но можно и вручную такое поведение реализовать со счетчиком, не забывая про `Intelocked.Increment` и `Interlocked.Decrement`.