# Как написать свой аналог Task.Delay?

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность

Я занимаюсь изучением асинхронного кода, идет очень туго. Я хочу написать свой собственный `Task.Delay`, потому что я не понимаю, как он устроен. Предположительно, у меня должен быть генератор (или что-то в таком духе), обозначающий, закончено ли ожидание, или пока рано.

Comment: Туго идет - это нормально. Если хотите, чтобы стало легче, сначала изучите многопоточность, научитесь писать потокобезопасный код, решать задачи типа [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1242773/373567) или [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219528/373567), изучите шаблон проектирования Producer/Consumer. И как только это начнет даваться легко, можно браться за таски и `async/await`, вот тогда пойдет не туго, а вполне уверенно.

Answer (score 1):

Написать свой `Task.Delay` можно, но сразу предупреждаю: при большом числе потоков то, что я напишу ниже, будет работать не так быстро как хотелось бы; в реальном коде есть ещё куча тонких оптимизаций.

Начнём с того, что потребуется контейнер для всех запланированных задач и объект для синхронизации:

```cs
private static PriorityQueue<TaskCompletionSource, long> queue = new();
private static object _lock = new();
```

Здесь используется приоритетная очередь на основе пирамиды (кучи, heap), которая упорядочит все задачи в порядке их выполнения. В реальном коде используется более сложная структура данных, которая всё ещё остаётся приоритетной очередью.

Теперь можно представить как будет выглядеть аналог метода Task.Delay:

```cs
public static async Task MyDelay(TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken token = default)
    => MyDelay((long)delay.TotalMilliseconds, token);
public static async Task MyDelay(int delay, CancellationToken token = default)
    => MyDelay((long)delay, token);

private static async Task MyDelay(long delay, CancellationToken token) {
    var task = new TaskCompletionSource(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
    var wakeupTime = Environment.TickCount64 + delay;
    
    lock(_lock) {
        queue.Enqueue(task, wakeupTime);
        // Если новая задача оказалась самой приоритетной - уведомим ожидающий поток
        if (queue.Peek() == task) Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
    }

    // тут бы удалить задачу из очереди, да вот PriorityQueue не поддерживает удаление,
    // поэтому просто отменяем задачу при отмене токена
    using (token.Register(() => task.TrySetCanceled())) {
        return await task.Task;
    }
}
```

Вроде все задачи сложены в очередь. Осталось создать поток который бы её "разгребал":

```cs
static MyTask() {
    new Thread(ProcessQueue) {
         Name = "MyTask.MyDelay process thread",
         IsBackground = true,
    }.Start();
}

const int MaxDelay = int.MaxValue / 2; // есть один баг...
private static void ProcessQueue() {
    while(true) {
        TaskCompletionSource task;

        lock(_lock) {
            if (!queue.TryPeek(out task, out wakeupTime)) {
                // Очередь пуста, ждём новых задач
                Monitor.Wait(_lock);
                continue;
            }
            else {
                var remaining = wakeupTime - Environment.TickCount64;
                if (remaining > MaxDelay)
                    remaining = MaxDelay;
                if (remaining > 0) {
                    // Очередь не пуста, но время очередной задачи ещё не наступило, надо подождать
                    Monitor.Wait(_lock, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(remaining));
                    continue;
                }
            }

            // Очередь не пуста, и время очередной задачи наступило
            queue.Dequeue();
        }

        task.TrySetResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень похоже на то, как устроен `ManualResetEventSlim`.

Comment: @aepot Ну, своего потока у ManualResetEventSlim, вроде бы, нет. Однако да, любые асинхронные примитивы в некотором смысле похожи: они все используют TaskCompletionSource или его внутренний аналог, складывают эти задачи в свои структуры данных и в нужные моменты сигнализируют о выполнении.

Comment: `Monitor.Pulse` => `Monitor.PulseAll`? Если нет, то почему?

Comment: @aepot потому что ждущий поток ровно один, тут не важно Pulse или PulseAll использовать.

Comment: тут опечатка? `queue.Enqueue(tcs, wakeupTime);` и должно было быть `task`? Либо наоборот переименовать переменную `task` в `tsc`?

Comment: @Grundy и вам спасибо

Comment: А как тогда мне в принципе написать свой асинхронный метод, который, например, выводит на экран последовательность чисел? (Предполагается, что Console.WriteLine будет блокировать этот поток, он же все равно работает быстро). То есть я хочу, например, создать 2 таски, которые будут по очереди выводить по числу в консоль. При помощи генераторов я представляю, как решить эту задачу, а при помощи асинхронного кода?

Comment: @Scrzii в вашей задаче нет смысла - проще и правильнее сделать **одну** задачу, которая последовательно выведет все числа в консоль

Comment: @Scrzii и да, какую связь вашего нового вопроса с реализацией Task.Delay вы видите?

Comment: @PavelMayorov я нашел то что хотел. Это оказался метод Task.Yield(). В чем была идея: я понимал, что await работает приблизительно как yield return в генераторах, он заставляет выходить из моей функции обратно в планировщик, пока не дождется результата выполнения метода, для которого стоит оператор await. Мне было интересно, есть ли метод, который заставляет выпрыгивать в планировщик просто так, сразу. Оказалось, есть - Task.Yield()